# XPath - not able to find an element with children text

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, xpath-2.0

```
<a>
    This is <var>Me</var> and That is <var> You</var>
</a>
```

I can find an element "a" which contains "This is" by following code:

```
//a[contains(text(),'This is')]
```

But I am not able to find element "a" which contains "This is Me and That is You".

```
//a[contains(text(),'This is Me and That is You')]
```

Is there a way to find an element with children text as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if this what you need but you can use string() to get the result as required,

```
//a[string()='This is Me and That is You']
```

The caveat however will be that you need to have precised information about the String being used.

#### See working example [here](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi?&data=%3Ca%3E%0A%20%20%20%20This%20is%20%3Cvar%3EMe%3C%2Fvar%3E%20and%20That%20is%3Cvar%3E%20You%3C%2Fvar%3E%0A%3C%2Fa%3E&=&extract=%2F%2Fa%5Bstring()%3D%27This%20is%20Me%20and%20That%20is%20You%27%5D%0A%0A%0A%0A%0A%0A%0A%0A%0A%0A%0A%0A%0A&=&input-format=auto&printed-node-format=text&output-format=adhoc&compatibility=Enable%20all%20extensions&dot-notation=unambiguous&extract-kind=auto).

Answer (score 1):

This also can be find using [`normalize-space()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/normalize-space) function of `xpath` which strips leading and trailing white-space from a string, replaces sequences of whitespace characters by a single space, and returns the resulting string as below :-

```
//a[normalize-space()='This is Me and That is You']
```